# Is it possible to set a default hat?

Tags: duck-game

In online matches the hat always resets (i.e. is removed) and I must every time set it manually. Finding the preferred one takes some time due the scrolling interface which only shows a handful of variants by default and this process has to be repeated again even when connecting to a new online lobby.

Is it possible to set a default hat?